# Salt residues on the bottom of dish washer

Tags: repair, dishwasher

I have started to seeing salt residues on the bottom of my machine after i moved to new flat.

I could tell that water in here is harder than my previous flat.

Comment: I assume you mean calcium compounds?  If you use the dishwasher detergent with softener, it should help keep the hard water from spotting the dishes and machine innards.   But if the bottom of the machine is collecting deposits, be sure the door isn't leaking around its seal

Comment: Is there  question in here somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the water to see how hard it is?  If not, I might start there to confirm this is indeed the issue you are facing.

Although it might not solve your problem, try running cycle or two without dishes but with a a couple of cups of vinegar added. Don't just pour it into the bottom, as it might get purged from the dishwasher's sump when the cycle starts.  Instead, put the vinegar in some sort of cup / dish so that it can "slosh out" as the cycle runs.

If this doesn't seem to make a difference, try using a different detergent (there are some, at least in the US, that claim to help with hard water).  Else, you might need a water softener.